How to know where the metrics in istio dashboard are in grafana or prometheus
I want to know how certain metrics in istio's kiali dashboard are searched for in prometheus or Grafana, such as full duration in applications-traces and how to calculate the response time of applications in the traffic graph of the overview.
I found the Inbound and Outbound metrics in Grafana , but don's kow how to found the Applications' traces and Overview metrics in Grafana or Prometheus

you can check the documentation where it says this:

Kiali uses the data stored in Prometheus to figure out the mesh topology, show metrics, calculate health, show possible problems, etc.
Kiali communicates directly with Prometheus and assumes the metrics used by Istio Telemetry

And those metrics came directly from istio standard metrics: https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/metrics/
